Balance three values based on user input to always some up to 100
I'm usually on Stackoverflow, so please bear with me, but I think this is more of a mathematical problem:
Imagine I have 3 input masks, I am calling them M1, M2, M3. These have an initial state of:
M1: 100, M2: 0, M3: 0

A user can change the value of each mask by entering a number of their choice between 0 - 100.
What I would like to do is to adjust the remaining masks depending on the new input of Mx.
So for example if a user enters M2: 50 the masks should resolve in:
M1: 50, M2: 50, M3: 0

If a user then enters 25 in M3, it should look like:
M1: 50, M2: 25, M3: 25

What I have tried so far is:
If M1 value X:
    M2 = 100 - M1 - M3
    M3 = 100 - M1 - M2
If M2 value X:
    M1 = 100 - M2 - M3
    M3 = 100 - M1 - M2
If M3 value X:
    M1 = 100 - M2 - M3
    M2 = 100 - M1 - M3

However, this will not always result in 100. I really need some help here.

If the initial state is  M1: 60, M2:40, M3: 0 then If I input M2: 60 will it be M1:40, M2:60, M3:0?

@OM the initial stats will be always 100,0,0 just after the mask interaction this changes. Ultimately the goal is that users can freely choose between 3 values of these three masks. It is just probably best to subtract from the former mask. But if the former mask is 0 it needs to be subtracted to the one before that. You see this is a bit mind boggling to me.

What if you add the remaining unchanged two mask values and subtract the input of the mask , then distribute to the remaining mask equally?  Is not it working? Do you have any more constrains other than M1+M2+M3 = 100?

@OM the input can be choosen freely, if I equally distribute, the former value will be overwritten.

M1: 100, M2: 0, M3: 0 ; user enters M2: 50 ->  M1: 25, M2: 50, M3: 25; user then enters 25 in M3 ->   M1: 37.5, M2: 37.5, M3: 25. What you mean by changing of the "former value will be overwritten"?

If the user changes $M_1$ to $M_1'$, you might try $$M_2' = \frac{M_2}{M_2+M_3}(100-M_1')$$ and $$M_3' = \frac{M_3}{M_2+M_3}(100-M_1')$$

@awkward and what happens if 2 to ′2, and 3  to ′3?
